# Is there a (necessary) redundancy in the migration format Add x to y?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, dry

To add the phone column to the tickets table, I can write:

```
ruby script/generate migration AddPhoneToTickets phone:string
```

There seems to be a redundancy here. But is it necessary?

Aren't we repeating ourselves by being required to  specify "phone" both in the name of the migration (`AddPhoneToTickets`) as well as in the column definition (`phone:string`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not *required* to put Phone in the migration name. For example, if you were adding a bunch of contact fields, you could just as easily call it `AddContactFieldsToTickets` and specify all the fields. It's not specific enough to use the name of the migration for anything but the table name, really.